# Renaming tabs in PL/SQL developer

Tags: plsqldeveloper

Currently in PL/SQL developer the default when returning multiple tabs in the tabs are named base on the first table in the from statement. However, for more complex queries where there are multiple joins this may not necessarily make sense. Is there a way to change the tab name in a more complex query?

Comment: This question may be better suited to the Allround Automations forum: http://www.allroundautomations.com/plsqldev.html

Answer (score 9):

In later editions of PL/SQL Developer you can use SQL Window tab directives, which are specifically formatted comments. For example, to name a tab "My Query" you would enter:

```
-- tab=My Query
select * from table1;
```

This is covered in the PL/SQL Developer help manual.

Answer (score 2):

I have no PL/SQL Developer right now, but, as I remember, you can make right click on tab name and select then "Rename" or something similar in popup menu. After that you can type new name for tab.

Comment: Doesn`t allow that in my version

Answer (score 0):

Type:

```
SET WORKSHEETNAME new_name
```

on your worksheet and press F9.
That's all!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).